# Fix navbar after scrolling and smoothly scroll content underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap's Affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) to fix my navbar to top after scrolling down 80px. Now this makes the navbar CSS to

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0
```

Since the navbar gets the position fixed and the element is not a part of the DOM anymore, the page content slides underneath the navbar as soon as the navbar gets affixed. To fix this, I've tried using JavaScript that adds a `margin-top` equal the height of the navbar to the content container after scrolling 80px.

Here is my JS code for that

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height >= 80) {
        $('.content-container').css('margin-top', '44px');
    } else {
        $('.content-container').css('margin-top', '0px');
    }
});
```

Now this works as expected but while the page is being loaded and the bootstrap javascript files are still being downloaded, the navbar doesn't get fixed to the top after scrolling and this gives a 'glitchy' experience. Is there a solution to this problem using CSS only?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Don't you _want_ content to appear under the affixed navbar? Otherwise the content will cover your navbar and people can't see it.

Comment: I think this is better fixed by making sure your js is loaded in the right order. I would use an AMD loader to make sure your bootstrap is loaded before this code is.

Comment: @AlexanderBird I want the content to appear under the affixed navbar. But as soon as the navbar gets affixed the content suddenly jumps underneath the navbar equal to the height of the affixed navbar (since it's not a part of the DOM anymore).

Comment: aah, so you're saying that it's lower than the nav bar according to the y-axis, and not the z-index. Right?  Also, your navbar is **definitely** in the DOM. There is not element which is not technically a part of the DOM; it just has a fixed position on the screen.

Comment: If you can, provide a snippet of the html and the javascript. Maybe your div which you use as the navbar should be placed elsewhere in you HTML so that it's not a sibling of the other elements constituting your page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `position:absolute` on my header to begin with, because that also takes it out of the flow, so I could take that into account from the start and keep the following content at bay via a margin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just wrap the "navbar" in a div with a min-height:44px?